# UIStoryboard 'init(name:bundle)' issue in RELEASE config

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I'm seeing following error when trying to build the app in `RELEASE` configuration. It seems all working fine when I build the same app in `DEBUG` mode.

> UIStoryboard 'init(name:bundle)' is unavailable: Use object
>   construction' UIStoryboard(name:bundle)' 'init(name:bundle)' has been
>   explicitly marked unavailable here.

I'm sure the same code was running fine few days back (without any error) in RELEASE config.

Here is the line which is throwing error:

> let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

I'm compiling this in Xcode Version **8.3.3 (8E3004b)**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems some Xcode or Swift compiler bug.
There was another error in the project (only in RELEASE config)

```
filteredFavoriteList = searchText.isEmpty ? [] : favoriteList.filter({(report: AnyObject) -> Bool in
    return report.reportTitle.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
})
```

As "report" of type AnyObject do NOT have any property "reportTitle", This piece of code was throwing error in relese config (it is working in debug config though).

I put the below fix for this as below:

```
filteredFavoriteList = searchText.isEmpty ? [] : favoriteList.filter({(report: AnyObject) -> Bool in
    if let report = report as? MyClass{
        return report.reportTitle.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
    }else{
        return false
    }
})
```

and now there is no more UIStoryboard errors and I'm able to build the app in release config.

So there is no error in this line but It was throwing error here due to some other reasons/errors.. Strange but TRUE.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
```

Thank you.

Comment: The entire use of AnyObject here is suspect. Granted, the error is confusing, but you should never have been doing this and you still should not be.